# Trying to get certain data from a json array in Angular, my method is only grabbing some of the data

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Here is what my JSON looks like:
[image]

Here is my method:

```
createUIListElements(){
    xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.uiListElement = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['UIInput'][0]['UIListElement'][0]['UIElement'];
      console.log(this.uiListElement);
      this.uiListElementArray = this.uiListElement.map((element: { $: any;}) => element);
      this.uiListElementArray.forEach((element: any) => {
        console.log(element);
      })
    })

  }
```

Right now it is only grabbing the `UIListElement` what I need is when I `console.log(element)` for it to display all of the `UIElement` data from both `UIListElement`

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using `'UIListElement'][1]` at all

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the array.
Based on your image I can write the logic like below.

```
createUIListElements(){
    xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.uiListElement = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['UIInput'][0]['UIListElement'][0]['UIElement'];
      console.log(this.uiListElement);
      this.uiListElementArray = this.uiListElement.map((element: { $: any;}) => element);
      this.uiListElementArray.forEach((element: any) => {
        console.log(element);
        element.UIElement.forEach((elem: any) => {
           console.log(elem)
        })
      })
    })

  }
```